# C Array leaking memory

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, memory-leaks

I have a simple program that just populates an array with numbers and prints each number.

However, valgrind claims there are at least 8000 bytes of memory leaked.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numbers[10];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = i;
        printf("%d",numbers[i]);
    }
    free(numbers);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can anyone explain where the memory leak is?

Is this the right way to free space allocated for an array?

Answer (score 7):

There is no memory leak, there is undefined behavior. You are deallocating the memory that has not been allocated, causing a problem.

You need to call `free` only on memory that has been allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. Calling `free` on any other memory location is undefined behavior. In your case, `numbers` is allocated in the automatic memory (otherwise known as "the stack"). This memory gets deallocated automatically as soon as it goes out of scope.

There are two ways to fix your program:

- Replace `int numbers[10];` with `int *numbers = malloc(10*sizeof(int));`, or
- Remove `free(numbers);`

Comment: even if I take away 'free(numbers)', valgrind still says there's a memory leak.

Comment: @nope What does it say exactly? Valgrind spits out several numbers, not all of them are claimed to be leaked.

Comment: ==8223== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8223==    definitely lost: 8,624 bytes in 14 blocks
==8223==    indirectly lost: 1,168 bytes in 5 blocks
==8223==      possibly lost: 4,925 bytes in 68 blocks
==8223==    still reachable: 47,851 bytes in 274 blocks
==8223==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8223== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==8223== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==8223== 
==8223== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8223== ERROR SUMMARY: 18 errors from 18 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: @nope Did you try running valgrind on an entirely empty program that returns `EXIT_SUCCESS` right away? In terms of leaking memory, there is little difference between your code and a code that does nothing.

Comment: i ran it on such a program, and the valgrind output is the same.

why does valgrind report a memory leak then?

and how would I know if there was a real memory leak?

Comment: @nope That's an excellent question. A quick search [reveals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11506370/335858) that this issue is not uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

0123456789Checking for memory leaks...

Actual leaks report    (actual leaks:            0  total size:          0 bytes)

Possible leaks report  (possible leaks:          0  total size:          0 bytes)

execution completed, exit code is 0

Here is the memory check report. There is no memeory leak.  Also you should use free only if you manually allocate the memory otherwise you should not use free.